# I cannot get the app to start. I get uncaughtype error util.isbrowser not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 3 angular 5 to make an app. when i run the app i get **uncaughtype error util.isbrowser not a function.** My dependencies are angularfire2: 5.1.0, firebase: 5.7.2. please help me with this. I have googled alot but cannot find any solution to it. The error is from node_modules/@firebase/app. The error occur on the highlighted part.

```
var logger = new logger$1.Logger('@firebase/app');
```

// Firebase Lite detection
if (**util.isBrowser()** && 'firebase' in self) {
    logger.warn("\n    Warning: Firebase is already defined in the global scope. Please make sure\n    Firebase library is only loaded once.\n  ");
    var sdkVersion = self.firebase.SDK_VERSION;
    if (sdkVersion && sdkVersion.indexOf('LITE') >= 0) {
        logger.warn("\n    Warning: You are trying to load Firebase while using Firebase Performance standalone script.\n    You should load Firebase Performance with this instance of Firebase to avoid loading duplicate code.\n    ");
    }
}

Comment: are you explicity trying to use `util.isbrowser`? show us some code!!!

Comment: I am not sure what this is. Its from inside node_modules/@firebase/app. @BizzyBob

Comment: Did you solved?  I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Hanzo, yes I was able to solve it. I was getting this error due to mismatch of plugins. All the plugins installed must be of the same version. My firebase version was not compatible with one of my plugins.